# How to find 50th percentile in postgres for date and time field?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, sql-function, percentile

How to find the 50th percentile date and time filed for example from below set in PostgreSQL

```
file_time
8/14/18 2:57:38
8/14/18 2:56:59
8/14/18 2:54:43
8/14/18 2:54:27
8/14/18 2:54:16
8/14/18 2:53:42
8/14/18 2:53:26
8/14/18 2:53:20
8/14/18 2:53:11
8/14/18 2:51:49
8/14/18 2:51:09
8/14/18 2:50:32
```

I tried to use below function in postgreSQL

```
percentile_disc(0.50) within group (order by file_time asc)
```

Can anyone tell me if this is correct way to find it?
Thanks

Comment: This should work.  Do you have an issue?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wanted to confirm if this is actually calculate the 50th Percentile or not as its timestamp data type